# MVC Identity with Database First

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-membership

I want to create an ASP.NET website, but I don't want any database modelling to happen in my MVC5 project.

I would like to put the entire database model in a seperate Database Project, Publish it to a server and then generate an .edmx file as my interface to the database.

I would like to know if there is a way to have the Identity library use the tables I define in my database project to administer users/roles.

I do not want to use `code first` or `model first` because I consider these unnecessary abstractions and too limited for my needs.

Comment: Code first gives you the most control.  Plus EF7 is dropping support for database first and model first.http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2014/05/19/ef7-new-platforms-new-data-stores.aspx

Comment: yes, you can do this.  Your edmx will generate `partial` classes.  Add to the `partial User` class and have it implement `IUser` and go from there with Identity

Comment: Actually, EDMX files are the unnecessary abstraction.  In fact, so much so that EF 7 is deprecating them.  As such, it's probably in your best interest to bite the bullet on new development and do things code first.